# I can't create build with expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

i already create app with react-native and it's run perfectly on local devices 
when i tried to create apk with

**exp build:android**

this error appear :- Standalone build failed!
then i run this command expo build:android errors
this is the result:-

**Can't read JSON file: /Users/mohamed/Desktop/oils/errors/package.json
[04:58:12] └─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mohamed/Desktop/oils/errors/package.json'
/[04:58:12] There is an error with your project. See above logs for information.
[04:58:12] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.**

here is my package.json file :-

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-carousel": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-photo-view": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.5",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-whc-toast": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-youtube": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "oils",
    "slug": "oils",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],

    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.kamatcho.oils"

    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.kamatcho.oils"
    }
  }
}
```

How i can fix that ??

Answer (score 0):

I think so

app.json

```
"sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
```

or
 new expo init newproject.

and

I recommend installing and executing all of the parts in "dependencies" or, if nothing wrong, putting a code in it to do it